# R - How to keep filtered data

Tags: r

I would like to ask, how do you keep the filtered values?

I have two data.tables, I want Xdata's num and value to be greater than Ydata's num -num2 and less than Ydata's value-value2.

```
      library(data.table)
      xdata <- data.table(ID=c("A","B","C","D","E","F"),
                         num=c("23","11","22",
                               "54","108","59"),
                         value=c("47","38","42",
                                 "86","189","90"))


      ydata <- data.table(ID=c("A","C","F"),
                         num=c("8","20","48"),
                        num2=c("26","26","60"),
                       value=c("40","34","78"),
                      value2=c("50","60","90"))

      library(dplyr)
      outputXY <- merge(xdata, ydata, by = "ID") %>% 
                  filter(num.x > num.y & num.x < num2 & value.x > value.y & value.x < value2) %>% 
                  select(-num.y, -num2, -value.y, -value2)
```

This output only

```
1. A  23 47
2. C  22 42
```

Because the value 90 of F does not reach the value2 condition of ydata, there is no F

Now I hope the output is

```
   ID num value
 1. B  11  38
 2. D  54  86
 3. E  108 189
 4. F  59  90
```

How can I modify it and do what I want?

Thank you

Comment: I am struggling to understand your question. You want to return the values that are not meeting you filtering criteria. By merging `by = "ID"`, you will never get `B,D,E`. You can retain them with `merge(xdata, ydata, by = "ID",all=T)`, but now you have `NAs` as there are missing values.  You may want to change the `filtering()` condition (maybe with an if condition? `if(A,C,F){} else { return B,D,E}`) 

Also if I run you code, `outputXY` only returns `C` , not `A and C`.

Comment: It should be said that I hope to get the reverse result

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `anti_join()` function from `dplyr` to get the complement like this:

```
xdata %>%
  anti_join(outputXY, by = "ID")
```

or in one step

```
xdata %>%
  anti_join(
    merge(xdata, ydata, by = "ID") %>% 
      filter(num.x > num.y & num.x < num2 & value.x > value.y & value.x < value2), 
    by = "ID"
  )
```

NOTE: Formatting your `num` and `value` columns as strings will lead to unexpected results. I strongly recommend using:

```
xdata <- data.table(ID=c("A","B","C","D","E","F"),
                    num=c(23,11,22,54,108,59),
                    value=c(47,38,42,86,189,90))


ydata <- data.table(ID=c("A","C","F"),
                    num=c(8,20,48),
                    num2=c(26,26,60),
                    value=c(40,34,78),
                    value2=c(50,60,90))
```

Comment: Thank you, but when adding data and having duplicates, it seems to be a bit wrong.I will try to modify